# Сколько раз встречается слово в файле?

Tags: c

Есть файл, в котором часто встречается слово set. Нужно подсчитать на СИ сколько раз оно встречается в этом файле.

Пока получилось вот что.

```
int main() {
 FILE *fd;
 int cnt=0;
 char buf[1024],*p;
 if ((fd=fopen("./file","r"))==NULL) printf("error");
 {
  while(fscanf(fd,"%s",buf)==1) {p=buf; while (p=strstr(p,"set")) {p++;cnt++;}}
  fclose(fd);
 }
 printf ("%i\n",cnt);
}
```

Работает, но почему то выдает после вывода Segmentation fault. И кстати файл наполняется свежими данными, может из-за того проблема?

Comment: `while(fscanf(fd,"%s",buf)==1) `

Comment: Извиняюсь, моя опечатка, но проблема не устранилась :)

Comment: Что значит "файл наполняется свежими данными"?

Comment: @kff другая программа дописывает каждый час новые строки.

Comment: Не знаю, у меня нет никакого Segmentation fault. Компилировал `gcc -o wordfile wordfile.c`.

Comment: Может по другому стоит составить программу?

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось банально и просто :) В файле встречались слова более 1024 байт. Нужно просто было увеличить буфер.

Comment: А теперь читаем [man getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) и используем для чтения эту функцию. Кстати, если `esets`, засчтанное, как `set` Вас устраивает, то безусловно, у Вас правильный алгоритм. Иначе проверяйте символы до и после `p = strstr(p, "set")`. Ну и p, после удачного поиска можно сразу увеличивать на 4.